# Jquery - Animate by scroll positions to work the same on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Hey I have this really annoying issue thats probably got a simple solution but for the life of me i cant find away to fix it.

Basically i have two images both 50% with of it's container now the goal is the both images to slide in (left/right) on the basis of the scroll position and once it get to the top of the container both images will sit is place.

Now i got that working to that point the only issue is when i resize the page the position of both images are wrong. I obviously did a resize() function with the same logic as the scroll() function but still i got nowhere. Here's my code

```
var page_width  =  $(document).outerWidth(),
            page_height =  $(document).outerHeight(),
            left_image  =  $('.split-screen.youth'),
            right_image =  $('.split-screen.elite'),
            offset      =  (page_width) / page_height;

        left_image.css({'left':'0px'});
        right_image.css({'right':'0px'});

        $(window).on('scroll', null, function(){
            var scrollTop =  $(window).scrollTop(),
                calc      =  -(scrollTop*offset); 

            left_image.css({
                'margin-left': 'calc(100% + '+calc+'px)'

            });

            right_image.css({
                'margin-right': 'calc(100% + '+calc+'px)'
            });
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            // something ???
        });
```

Here is a jsFiddle of the issue although it doesn't look entirely accurate but you get the picture. When you resize the scroll position changes and i need the margin-left/margin-right values to be correct.

Comment: We need more information to determine exactly what the problem is and what you're trying to display.  Can you provide some screenshots of the problem and a mock up of what you want to achieve?  Maybe a JSFiddle would help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a7tfmp37/

Comment: Well if I resize the jsfiddle in Chrome the browser is resizing the images correctly. Maybe you're using a specific browser ?

Comment: Try again i put in a reload into the demo by mistake

Comment: Well, they are overlapping maybe is that your issue? OK, I see you're reloading it :)

Comment: No thats is only happening in fiddle it doesn't happen on my actual work

Comment: answer added. You're just using the old page_width/height and offset values. On resize you should update them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're still using the old offset value. Just update your global values first, than it works for me (see: https://jsfiddle.net/a7tfmp37/2/):

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    page_width  =  $(document).outerWidth(),
    page_height =  $(document).outerHeight(),
    offset      =  (page_width) / page_height;
    var scrollTop =  $(window).scrollTop(),
        calc      =  -(scrollTop*offset); 
    left_image.css({
        'margin-left': 'calc(100% + '+calc+'px)'

    });

    right_image.css({
        'margin-right': 'calc(100% + '+calc+'px)'
    });
});
```

Comment: That does't work - when you scale down it work but then when you scale up it does not.

Comment: What do you want exactly? When I resize the browser (make it thinner) the images are getting smaller and when I make it larger the images get large? Do you also want to scale when I'm changing the heigth?

Comment: i want the container to always be 100% and the images to always be 50% this is fine - it's just the scroll position thats not.

Comment: so you don't want the images to "overlap" ?

Comment: Well, the "simplest" thing was to make your container height not 100vh, 98vh fits

Comment: Thats not the problem though is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92390/discussion-between-fer-to-and-john-williams).